# iframe not showing content in html

Tags: php, html, iframe

**toonzaal.php** (html page but php code included -> thats why .php)

```
<iframe data-src="toonzaal.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="height:600px"></iframe>
```

[image]

The empty space is the iframe I guess but don't know why nothing more is showing.

**toonzaal.html**

this is a slider (pictures) that I want to show smaller in the toonzaal.php page

[image]

[image]

**Folder structure**

[image]

Comment: pictures of code are utterly useless. we're not going to haul out a microscope to try and figure out what's in that code.

Comment: I just add them to try to give as much information as I can... what the hell is your problem anyway..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [w3 html5 reference on embedded content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element) there is no such attribute as`data-src` for `iframe` element.

You should use `src` instead.

```
<iframe src="toonzaal.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="height:600px"></iframe>
```

Should work.

**Additionally**:

`Frameborder` attribute is obsolete in HTML5. You can use CSS for that. In your case it will be `border: none;`.

While `scrolling` is also obsolete in HTML5, most of browsers still support it and they doesn't work well with `overflow: hidden;` css property for `iframe` element. That's why your `iframe` should look like this:

```
<iframe src="toonzaal.html" scrolling="no" style="height:600px; border: none;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you mate! That was indeed the solution!

Comment: @user3360972 Anytime! Glad it worked. :)